# TOR Browser hangs up when maximized on Windows 11

Tags: windows

I had installed Windows 11 and started TOR Browser (from a non-system drive, where it was installed earlier). It was running well, even if I maximized the window.

But now (after an update or something, not sure) every time I try maximizing the window, it immediately hangs up. Just resizing the window nevertheless works fine. If I don't maximize, it runs well and I can connect to the network and open sites.

Other applications (including regular Firefox) don't have the maximizing problem.

Is that a TOR browser issue or a one related to Windows 11? How can I workaround it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your windows to the point, no such issue in the last updated one: we've done a fresh install with an upgrade from Windows 10 and initially Windows 11 was a bit glitchy, but after an updates were completed - no problems so far, including Tor browser that we've installed and tried maximizing and resizing it too. Just push it up by going to Settings - Security and Updates - Update center and forcibly press to detect any until it's done. We have used Bit Defender free antivirus instead of the built-in one and installed AMD Software : Adrenalin Edition for the CPU+GPU fresh drivers